# Explain why the set is not in the basis R3

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

Hello there math community,

I have an idea on how to solve this  and this is it:

> > I know that vectors of a basis need to be linearly independent.

If each vector is written out it can be observed that R1 +R2 = R3. Therefore  the vectors are not linearly independent.

> > Is There anything else that could be said about why this set isn't in the basis?

Comment: What do you know about the size of bases of $\mathbb{R}^3\hspace{-0.02 in}$? ​ ​

Comment: I think you mean "$-R_1+R_2=R_3$" . . .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition of dimension is the largest possible number of vectors in any linearly independent subset of the space.

A basis is a maximal linearly independent subset, i.e. a linearly independent subset having a number of vectors equal to the dimension of the space.

The standard basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$ is $\{(1,0,0),(0,1,0),(0,0,1)\}$, it has three elements, thus the dimension of $\mathbb{R}^3$ is three.

The set given above has more than three elements; therefore it can not be a basis, since the number of elements in the set exceeds the dimension of $\mathbb{R}^3$. Therefore some subset must be linearly dependent.